# Request for revert of the top bar background colour

Tags: feature-request, design

I would like to request that the background colour of the top bar gets reverted to the previous warm brownish. There are three reasons for this:

1. The black top bar is the most emphasized element of the site now, which is surely not the intention.
2. Its colour doesn't fit the warm, smooth and pleasant look of the site at all.

Thank you.

Comment: Reg: UI functionality: One Click button from `meta` to `main tex.sx` and vice-versa, One Click `chat` button is missing. If One Click `blog` is also available it would be great !

Comment: I also miss the feature that I can click on my reputation counter to got to the reputation page (of my profile) and to the main page of my profile, when clicking on my name. Now its just a big button always leading to the main profile page …

Comment: @texenthusiast On main the link to meta is included into help, from meta to main you can get by clicking on the “StackExchange” button.

Comment: @Speravir Yes, I know, maybe i am too lazy hence asking for `One Click buttons` for `chat` `blog` `meta` definitely _I_ don't care of `rep box`,`logout`,`achievements` and `help` if it were accessed in multiple clicks but may be SE cares to encourage users.

Comment: I think, [style sheets and/or user scripts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210041) will help the most with points 1 and 2, maybe even 3 with a little bit of work.

Comment: With all the craziness about the new top bar: It reminds me of someone pointing out differences between **inovating** and **improving**...

Comment: although it is partly a problem (unfixable) with the monitor i'm using, the reverse type (white on black) is *very* hard to read.  the other comments about the "disappeared" meta and chat are also applicable (it was really hard to find that little triangle next to "help").

Comment: What I forgot to mention yesterday: Both main and meta are reachable from the site switcher.

Comment: What's the third reason?

Answer (score 23):

Forget what I just said, Sean's link is way better than my pathetic implementation. `:)`

[image: Click here!]

[Is anyone else personally terrified of the new bar at the top?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209957/is-anyone-else-personally-terrified-of-the-new-bar-at-the-top/210013#210013)

If you want to keep the avatars, just comment the following part of the code:

```
/*

  .user-gravatar32,
  .gravatar,
  .avatar-me {
    display: none !important;
  }

*/
```

woohoo! `:)`

---

<sub>The following text is kept for historical reasons.</sub>

I'm really enraged, so desperate times call for desperate measures. `:)`

I decided to go with [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/) and add the following script to both meta and main:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix("http://meta.tex."), url-prefix("http://tex.") {

  .topbar, .topbar a, .topbar:hover, .topbar a:hover {
    background-color:#F5F5F5 !important;
    color:black !important;
  }

}
```

You will probably recognize this `.css`, right? `:)`

The resulting top bar I get with the previous code is

[image: Quack]

which is way lighter than the original dark colour. `:)`

Comment: Nice idea; personally I would change the `StackExchange` logo as seen in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210013/188148).

Comment: Thanks for this Paulo!!!

Comment: @Sean: Very nice, thank you! `:)`

Answer (score 13):

Going by [the blog post announcing/explaining the change](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/), it sounds like your main request of a colour revert is unlikely to be granted:

> So, in the redesigned top bar, we wanted to make sure that it would look the same across all sites, and make it obvious that you’re on a Stack Exchange site. It turns out that when you try to pick a color to match 40 different site designs, you quickly realize you only have one real choice: black.

Re your other suggestions, the post also points to [the `top-bar` tag on `meta.stackoverflow`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/top-bar) as the main way to give feedback on the new design.

Comment: Why spoiling is called redesigning?

Comment: If they wanted to make it obvious I'm on a SE site, why did they make it look just like a WordPress site?

Comment: »make it obvious that you’re on a Stack Exchange site« - yes, the word “StackExchange” obviously doesn't communicate that! But if you land on a page with an ugly black bar dominating everything you see know you're there... what I'm still missing is some huge ads fading in telling me to do something and only after I've done so I can read the pages contents again

Comment: thanks for that link; i hadn't seen it, and was surprised by the new appearance.  (and i much prefer the old one.)

Comment: What was wrong with a white bar?

Comment: Why AskUbuntu has a purple bar?

Comment: Well, Ask Ubuntu had to be customised anyway, @Kartik, because it's officially in partnership with Canonical and has the Canonical bar above the SE bar. And if it's going to be customised anyway, it may as well use a colour which (a) is an official Ubuntu colour, and (b) matches the site theme.